# How to grep multiple rows?

Tags: grep

I have two tables. Table 1 sample has multiple columns and table 2 has one column.
My question is, how can i extract rows from table 1 based on values in table 1.
I guess a simple grep should work  but how can i do a grep on each row. Thanks!

Table 1:

```
IPI00436567;    Q6VEP3;
IPI00169105;IPI01010102;    Q8NH21;
IPI00465263;    Q6IEY1;
IPI00465263;    Q6IEY1;
IPI00478224;    A6NHI5;
IPI00853584;IPI00000733;IPI00166122;    Q96NU1-1;Q96NU1-2;
IPI00411886;IPI00921079;IPI00385785;    Q9Y3T9;
IPI01010975;IPI00418437;IPI01013997;IPI00329191;    Q6TDP4;
IPI00644132;IPI00844469;IPI00030240;    Q494U1-1;Q494U1-2;
IPI00420049;IPI00856062;    Q5SV97-1;Q5SV97-2;
IPI00966381;IPI00917954;IPI00028151;    Q9HCC6;
IPI00375631;    P05161;
IPI00374563;IPI00514026;IPI00976820;    O00468;
IPI00908418;    E7ERA6;
IPI00062955;IPI00002821;IPI00909677;    Q96HA4-1;Q96HA4-2;
IPI00641937;IPI00790556;IPI00889194;    Q6ZVT0-1;Q6ZVT0-2;Q6ZVT0-3;
IPI00001796;IPI00375404;IPI00217555;    Q9Y5U5-1;Q9Y5U5-2;Q9Y5U5-3;
IPI00515079;IPI00018859;    P43489;
IPI00514755;IPI00004233;IPI00106646;    Q9BRK5-1;Q9BRK5-2;
IPI00064848;    Q96L58;
IPI00373976;    Q5T7M4;
IPI00375728;IPI86;IPI00383350;  Q8N2K1-1;Q8N2K1-2;
IPI01022053;IPI00514605;IPI00514599;    P51172-1;P51172-2;
```

Table 2:

```
IPI00000207
IPI00000728
IPI00000733
IPI00000846
IPI00000893
IPI00001849
IPI00002214
IPI00002335
IPI00002349
IPI00002821
IPI00003362
IPI00003419
IPI00003865
IPI00004233
IPI00004399
IPI00004795
IPI00004977
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: You may find an answer here: [Matching text using grep or awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458074/matching-text-using-grep-or-awk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-f` option that takes a file as argument

```
grep -f table2 table1
```

Comment: You'll want to swap table1 and table2.

Comment: correct, I was just going to do that. Thanks...

Comment: Also, it won't matter in this case, but it would be good to get in the habit of using `-F` too.

Comment: To add more. I guess, `-Fwf` is the right option.

Comment: @iamauser cool. how can i retain the original column from table 2 in my final output?